# scheduledTimer not stopping another ViewController in swift 5

Tags: swift

I have set scheduledTimer in a  view Controller. But when got to anther view controller, previous view controller timer is continue.Here is my code

```
var timer: Timer? = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimedCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Here is function

```
  @objc func runTimedCode() {
     //Api Calling


     }
```

when I go to anther viewController, previous Api calling is continue. 
Please help me to scheduledTimer go another page/viewcontroller

Comment: Just call `timer?.invalidate()` when you leave.

Comment: @Don I have used it but not stop

Comment: The timer should not fire if you call invalidate within 10 seconds. If it's already fired and you're trying to cancel your API calls when moving to a new view controller, then that's more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you may not be calling **invalidate** on the same thread as where you installed the timer. For example, if you installed in on the main thread, wrap **invalidate** in:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

       self.timer.invalidate()

})
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1415405-invalidate

Answer (score 1):

Timer holds strong reference to current view controller even if your app goes into background or inactive state it still active . Also whenever you push new controller timer is not stoped at all .

Even if you pop your controller it still don't stop timer at this moment . However timer would start with double speed if you initialise timer again . let's understand this problem .

Lets  have 3 controllers

```
 HomeScreenVC --> TimerControllerVC --> NewVC
```

When you initialise timer in `TimerController` . It create strong reference to your TimerController . Now push `NewVC` controller on some action method , timer is not stopped at this moment it is still running .

Same case happens with if you pop `TimerControllerVC` controller to `HomeScreenVC` . Now you again pushing `TimerControllerVC` and initialising fresh timer in some method . This time timer would work with **2x** speed irrespective of new timer created timer . It creates cycle of recreation if you repeat this step .

Resolving timer issue , remember whenever you declare timer , you must invalidate it in viewwilldissappear method of UIViewcontroller .

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        timer.invalidate()
}
```

**Invalidating timer in some other self declare methods will not helps because there are always some cases when your self declare is not called which will lead to some unexpected issue with timer .**

Comment: thank you very much but it won't work override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
           super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
          
        timer!.invalidate()
       }

Comment: try viewWillDisappear  .

Comment: I tried invalidating timer in viewWillDisappear but still timer is hitting not stopping can you please guide if I am missing some other stuff which needs to do.

Comment: set timer = nil , see timer creation and invaliding should be in same class to avoid multiple copies of timer.